# Comparing pass-by-value with pass-by-reference performance by looking at assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, visual-c++, clang

I want to test a function in order to verify which one is faster, pass-by-value or pass-by-reference

Here is my test case : https://godbolt.org/g/cjaEx3

code :

```
struct Vec4f
{
  float val[4];
};


Vec4f suma(const Vec4f& a, const Vec4f& b)
{
  return {a.val[0] + b.val[0], 
          a.val[1] + b.val[1],
          a.val[2] + b.val[2],
          a.val[3] + b.val[3]};
}

Vec4f sumb(Vec4f a, Vec4f b)
{
  return {a.val[0] + b.val[0], 
          a.val[1] + b.val[1],
          a.val[2] + b.val[2],
          a.val[3] + b.val[3]};
}
```

assembly's output on x86-64 clang using `-O3 -std=c++14`:

```
suma(Vec4f const&, Vec4f const&):                     # @suma(Vec4f const&, Vec4f const&)
        movq    xmm1, qword ptr [rdi]   # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
        movq    xmm0, qword ptr [rsi]   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
        addps   xmm0, xmm1
        movq    xmm2, qword ptr [rdi + 8] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero
        movq    xmm1, qword ptr [rsi + 8] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
        addps   xmm1, xmm2
        ret

sumb(Vec4f, Vec4f):                        # @sumb(Vec4f, Vec4f)
        addps   xmm0, xmm2
        addps   xmm1, xmm3
        ret
```

It turns out on gcc, clang, and msvc that passing by value produces fewer assembly in this particular case.

My questions are :

1. Is comparing assembly line count generally is a good heuristic for comparing performance of simple functions like these?

and also as I don't really understand the assembly output

2. Can you explain the assembly output of both `suma` and `sumb` function?

Interestingly, if I change Vec4f to have `float val[40]` instead, both functions produce the same assembly output. So,

3. What's the reason of the initial assembly difference?

Comment: These small functions usually get inlined in production, so you should rather use the variant which makes your source easier to read + maintain. After you have your whole code finished, and correct, then you can profile it and fix bottlenecks. Mind you, if your code will do anything non-trivial, even the somewhat less optimal reference variant from your question will result in tiny performance penalty, you will likely find many other bottlenecks elsewhere, before getting to the point where argument passing tuning will be worth of attention. During that easy-to-read+maintain code is a win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No.  Not all instructions execute in the same amount of time, and once memory needs to be accessed there can be a large latency.

2) and 3).  `suma` needs to load the contents of `a` and `b` into appropriate registers.  In `sumb`, those values are passed to the function already in the registers.  In some cases, the register loading in `suma` will be done by `sumb`'s caller.  In other cases, the values may already be in registers, and the `suma` caller will first need to store those values in memory so that it can create references to them.

When you use `float val[40]` that exceeds the capacity for passing values by register, so both functions will need to load the data from memory first (in `suma`, by dereferencing the reference; in `sumb` by loading the values off the stack).

Comment: Leading to a rule: anything that is register-sized should be passed by-value (unless you actually *need* by-ref semantics.)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Maybe this can be used as a heuristic, but it cannot be trusted at all. For example, a simple `div` instruction can be slower than 20 simple instructions. So I wouldn't bother looking at instruction counts at all.

**2), 3)**

Here's a little explanation the assembly you listed:

clang only uses half of the vector registers (xmmX can contain 4 float values, but clang only uses 2). Maybe it is because of calling conventions.

```
// this function has two reference parameters
// register rdi points to the first parameter (points to, so it is not the value of it, but a pointer)
// register rsi points to the second parameter
// register xmm0, xmm1 contains the result
suma(Vec4f const&, Vec4f const&):
        movq    xmm1, qword ptr [rdi]   # xmm1 will contain the first 2 floats of the first parameter
        movq    xmm0, qword ptr [rsi]   # xmm0 will contain the first 2 floats of the second parameter
        addps   xmm0, xmm1              # let's add them together, xmm0 contains the result
        movq    xmm2, qword ptr [rdi + 8] # xmm2 will contain the second 2 floats of the first parameter
        movq    xmm1, qword ptr [rsi + 8] # xmm1 will contain the second 2 floats of the second parameter
        addps   xmm1, xmm2              # let's add them together, xmm1 contains the result
        ret

// this function has to parameters
// first is passed in xmm0 and xmm1
// seconds is passed in xmm2 and xmm3
// register xmm0, xmm1 contains the result
sumb(Vec4f, Vec4f):
        addps   xmm0, xmm2
        addps   xmm1, xmm3
        ret
```

> if I change `Vec4f` to have `float val[40]` instead, both functions produce the same assembly output.

**This is false**. They don't. They seem to be the same at first sight, but they are not.

There's code in both functions that is the same: because you return a `float[40]`, which has a lot of zero members, there should be code in both functions that zeros these elements. You see that code, and it is the same. The other parts differ.

Comment: The quoted claim has a condition attached to it: "if I change `Vec4f` to have `float val[40]` instead". With that condition in place, the claim appears to be correct. It now has to pass the struct containing the array by-reference because it is too large to pass by-value (i.e., directly in a register).

Comment: The reason it uses only half of the vector registers when loading from memory is that it's easier to do it that way. There are plenty of vector registers to go around, and just using two of them means you don't have to do a shift/pack to move the data into the upper bits. (Or even `movhps`.) Besides that, it wants to add them together, so if they were packed into a single vector register, you'd have to do a horizontal add.

Comment: @CodyGray: yep, it is not passed directly in registers. But it is passed by value. Parameters are on the stack for the second case (two, 40-element float array in the stack), while in the first case, they are passed by reference (just two pointers in the stack).

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I thought the annotated code below that in the answer was attempting to illustrate the difference. I would maybe reorder that to put the disassembly first, and the quotation+response second.

Comment: @CodyGray: This is the same code the OP listed. He/she wanted to understand this code in 2), that's why the order. But I see what you mean, I'll try to make my answer a little bit more clear.